# how to understand composition and forwarding methods?

Tags: java, oop, composition

Effective in Java Item 16:

> Luckily, there is a way to avoid all of the problems earlier. Instead of extending an existing class,give your new class a private field that reference a existing class.

Then I got the code to explain in details:

```
public class InstrumentedSet<E> extends FowardingSet<E> {
    private int addCount = 0;

    public InstrumentedSet(Set<E> s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        addCount++;
        super.add(e);
    }

    ...

    public int getCount() {
        return addCount;
    }
}

public class ForwardingSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private final Set<E> s;
    public ForwardingSet(Set<E> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return s.add(e);
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm feeling confused: where is the private reference? and I saw the extends keywords obviously, so where is the composition in the code?

Comment: It's probably in the definition of `ForwardingSet`.

Comment: Which edition of Effective Java is this? In the 2nd edition, Item 18 is "Prefer Interfaces to Abstract Classes". Are you talking about Item 16?

Comment: @vivin you'r correct. It's a typo mistake. I've updated the text also.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is at:

```
private final Set<E> s;
```

s is set through the constructor

```
ForwardingSet(Set<E> s)
```

and the child constructor

```
InstrumentedSet(Set<E> s)
```

that calls super(s);

InstrumentedSet is a wrapper for the underling FowardingSet, and forwards the calls there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ForwardingSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private final Set<E> s;
                         ^-- here is the private reference
```

The ForwardingSet implements the Set interface by forwarding, or delegating, all its methods to another Set. This is the decorator pattern in action.